# else-if returns unexpected '<='

Tags: r, if-statement

Can someone tell me whats wrong with my R code:

```
       for (i in 1:6)
    {
      probability_of_x[i] = i/21
    }
    U = runif(1,0,1)
    
    if(U<=probability_of_x[1]){
  X=1
  print("X = 1")
  }else if(probability_of_x[1]<U<=probability_of_x[2]){
  X=2
  print("X = 2")
  } else if(probability_of_x[2]<U<=probability_of_x[3]){
  X=4
  print("X = 3")
  } else if(probability_of_x[3]<U<=probability_of_x[4]){
  X=4
  print("X = 4")
  } else if(probability_of_x[4]<U<=probability_of_x[5]){
  X=5
  print("X = 5")
  } else(probability_of_x[5]<U<=probability_of_x[6]){
  X=6
  print("X = 6")}
```

I get the error:

> Error: unexpected '<=' in: "  print("X = 1")   }else
> if(probability_of_x[1]<U<="

Comment: You can't use multiple equality statements at once. Use ``a < b & a > c`` instead.

Comment: And you can simplify the initial `for` loop: `probability_of_x <- (1:6)/21`.

Comment: after the last `else` there is no `if` in your code. You can't (directly ) apply a condition to an `else`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do in between operator like that (`1 < 2 < 3`)

Instead use 2 statements with an and - `1 < 2 & 2 < 3`
or with `dplyr` package - `between(2, 1, 3)`

Comment: Hi, I fixed this now and the code runs, however I get no output printed in the console?